# Layout not displaying correctly

Tags: java, android, android-layout

A strange thing is happening, I have the exactly same activities, but in one of them, the buttons in the layout appear out of bounds if I add the following code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

I have this code in others activities as well but only in this one this error occurs. And it only occurs on some android versions, from 4.4 to 6.0 works fine. 
Yes, I've checked, if I remove this line from the code, it works perfectly, but if add it back my buttons appear out of bounds, and it's only the left button. [image: Wrong layout]

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mimica);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.Toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to play with gravity and layout_gravity,

***android:gravity*** : It sets the gravity of the contents (i.e. it's sub views) of the View it's used on.
***android:layout_gravity*** : It sets the gravity of the View or Layout relative to its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that your XML file is good?

Comment: Yeah, both xmls are the same.

Comment: can you please share your xml file

Comment: Yeap. Share the XML

Comment: I may be late to the party but read up on the difference between layout_gravity and simply gravity